# Best way to capture click event on dynamically loaded images

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using Eclipse Juno (with latest patches), the latest GWT and java.

I am loading images into a flextable with the associated surname and firstname concatenated and displayed beneath each image in a 7 x n grid. What I want to do now is give each image a unique name and assign a click handler to it. I will then pick up a click event on an image a display the next view populated with that person's details.

Is a flextable the correct widget to use for this or should I use a different widget to contain the image and name?

How do I give each image a unique name so I know which image was selected?

How do I pass the unique image name to the onClick listener?

This is the code I am using:

```
public void renderYouthMemberTable(List<YouthMember> youthMemberList) {
    if (youthMemberList != null) {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        flexTable.clear();
        for (YouthMember youthMember : youthMemberList) {
            String imageDataString = youthMember.getPhotograph();

            //Display each image with the name under it.
            Image image = new Image(imageDataString);
            flexTable.setWidget(row, col, image);
            flexTable.setWidget(row + 1, col, new Label(youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname()));

            //Add click handler
            image.addClickHandler((ClickHandler) this);

            //Go to next column and if the end of the columns
            //drop two rows and go to the first column
            col = col + 1;
            if (col > 7) {
                row = row + 2;
                col = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}   


public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // note that in general, events can have sources that are not Widgets.
    Widget sender = (Widget) event.getSource();

    if (sender == image) {
        // handle image1 being clicked
        }
    else if (sender == image2) {
        // handle image2 being clicked
    }
}
```

onClick does not work yet. This is just here to show what I want to achieve.

Thanks for your help,

Glyn

Comment: Is the `//handle image1 being clicked` and the `//handle image2 being clicked` doing the same thing just with a different image?

Comment: Hi NickD, yes they will both (and all others) pass control to the next view with the id of the person selected so that person's details are displayed in the view. Thanks, Glyn.

Comment: image.addClickHandler((ClickHandler) this) looks fishy? what type is "this" !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the flex table is fine for your use case.

For the click event why dont you do it inline?

```
image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
        // Do something
    }

});
```

This way you don't need to deal with firing events or using an `EventBus`.

If you need to store any other information with the image just extend `Image` and add whatever you need. Although you probably won't need this information if you implement your click handlers like above.

For example:

```
public class MyImage extends Image{

    private String id;

    public MyImage(String url){
        super(url);
    }

    public MyImage(String url, String id){
        super(url);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

}
```

Then just use `MyImage` instead of `Image`.

**UPDATE:**
Added contructors

Comment: Hi enrybo, This is what I need. I have created the class MyImage however when I try to assign a value "final MyImage myImage = new MyImage(imageDataString);" I get the error "The constructor MyImage(String) is undefined". As this extends Image we should be able to do the same as "Image image = new Image(imageDataString);". We are just adding the ability to include the ID. The next line "myImage.setId(youthMember.getId());" is OK. Do I need to repeat the String code in the MyImage class for the Image? Or have I done something else wrong? Thanks for your help, Glyn.

Comment: All you need to do is add the constructor that I added above. Please note that you need to call `super()` in order to call the constructor of the parent class. You can call `super()` with any of the constructors of the parent class but you have to make sure that the `super()` call has to be the first statement in the constructor.

Comment: Hi enrybo, Thank you very much. I have been experimenting with this and found this out. That is, that I do not need the class as you say as the id is associated with the image. I do not fully understand how that is without the class and manually associating the id with the image. That is homework for me! I greatly appreciate your help. I am in the process of creating a blog tutorial of this project (a Wood Badge project for my advanced Scout Leader training) and I will ensure I mention you and all the other people that have helped me. Regards, Glyn.